# 2 simple errors in php

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I will probably get down voted to oblivion like i always do, but here goes.

Error Codes:

> $Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:   YES) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mine/includes/class_database.php on line 9
>
> $Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mine/includes/class_database.php on line 10
> Could not connect to database. Please contact the webmaster.

These are the lines

Line 9

```
$this->Connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or $error = true;
```

Line 10

```
mysql_select_db($name, $this->Connection) or $error = true;
```

I have tried declaring them like this:

```
$host="localhost"
$host=localhost
$host"'localhost'
$host = "localhost"
$host = localhost
$host=localhost"
```

and i have tried with

```
' ´ ` "
```

Comment: Your login credentials are incorrect. You need to figure out why.

Comment: Not having a valid password (issue #1) explains why you cannot run queries on the database (issue #2). As far as we can tell, none of these are related to PHP at all. Do you need help to reset your MySQL password?

Comment: They are not, i have tried with no single password at all and it still says this.

Comment: It's probably a wording issue but you seem to suggest that your password can't be wrong because when you try a really wrong password you get the same "access denied" error :-?

Answer (score 1):

since the connection fails, `$this->Connection` is (bool) false. That's why you get the second warning.

Regarding the first one, it's not that you're entering your host wrong. 'localhost' is fine. The problem is that 'root', with that password, isn't allowed for localhost.

Check your mysql to make sure about the password. Also, please note that user permission in mysql are host based. You could have a root@localhost with password1, and root@% with password2.

Other ideas to check

- how do you know the db password?
- did you set any when installing XAMPP?
- have you got phpmyadmin installed?

  if yes, can you log with phpmyadmin?

  if you don't, can you log from shell using `mysql -u root -p` ?
- perhaps there's no password and you can log just with `mysql -u root`.
- If everything else fails, reset your mysql password.

Comment: Could not connect to database. Please contact the webmaster.